# Catch InvalidConfigurationException and FileLoaderLoadException

Tags: symfony, exception

I want to make a command that checks if all bundles are well configured so I'm trying to catch both of

```
Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException

Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException
```

I tried with an event listener but the exceptions seems to occure before the event .How can I catch those types of exception before the execution of my command .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Configuration loaded during container building, before command execution.